# How make material UI Tab component auto Scrollable in react

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

I am using material design UI react components for frontend in react , I am getting issue with the tabs , I want that when click on any of the mention tab the page automatically scroll bit down , right now when i click that tab page does not scrolls

I tried with react scroll module but it does not give the result , instead it throws me to the end of page ,

demo example : https://codesandbox.io/s/yko6x8r0wz

When Click on PageOne within in Tab section , it should scroll down a bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I made a SPA I used this library: [react-router-hash-link](https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link). 
It has a hash link that manages the smooth scrolling by sections.

A tutorial with link examples is [this](https://reactjsexample.com/hash-link-scroll-functionality-for-react-router/).

You could define the new Link in the tab section this way:

```
import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link';
<Link to="/menu#section-a">Link to Section A</Link>
```

I hope although if it isn't the same library it can help you :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the variant= scrollable.

```
<Tabs
  value={false}
  indicatorColor="primary"
  textColor="primary"
  variant="scrollable"
  scrollButtons="auto"
>
```

This should work. Thank you.